# Typescript + Eslint false positive for imports + `declare global`

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

My `.d.ts. file looks like this:

```
import type { typesAsObj } from 'entityTypes';

declare global {
  type EntityType = keyof typeof typesAsObj;
}
```

This produces:

```
'typesAsObj' is not defined. eslint no-undef
```

However, this works:

```
import type { typesAsObj } from 'entityTypes';

type _EntityType = keyof typeof typesAsObj;

declare global {
  type EntityType = _EntityType;
}
```

Why doesn't the first one work?

Comment: That rule is incredibly problematic for typescript code. You should disable it if you want sanity

Answer (score 3):

Turn off "no-undef": "off"(disallow the use of undeclared variables unless mentioned in `/*global */` comments) and to be handled by the typescript compiler itself.

or

*Use*
The "extends": "eslint:recommended" property in a configuration file

```
 "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended", //<---
        'plugin:jasmine/recommended',
        'plugin:jsdoc/recommended'
    ],
```

Comment: I would also add [**typescript-eslint**](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) for typescript support in eslint